# Django set boolean after opening record

Tags: django, boolean, user-controls

I have been googling for a good hour and I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this. In my applicants model I have this field `viewed = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Nieuw", default=False)`
which gets shown on the admin page table for this model `list_display = ('viewed', 'custom_status', 'updated_at', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'vacancy', 'created_at', 'applicant_actions')`

But how do I set that boolean to true when a user opens the applicant's detail page?
Thanks in advance